# How to look if the value reoccurs in the table after current selection in SQL

Tags: sql, case-when

I have below data table [CRA_feasibility_test]

```
atmid       CRA     monday  tuesday wednesday   thursday    friday  saturday
DA0068C1    ABC       Y      N      Y           N           N        Y
```

I want to select the data based on the weekday of my date.If it is Y then want to get closest 'Y' i.e the day when it will be Y from the @date.

And also i want to get next

I am doing the following

```
declare @date datetime set @date ='2018-06-15' 
Select  @dateT as indentdate, DATENAME(dw,@dateT) as weekdayname,

          case when DATENAME(dw,@dateT)  ='monday'        
                                                 then  monday

                  when DATENAME(dw,@dateT)  ='tuesday'           then  
                                                            tuesday
                  when DATENAME(dw,@dateT)  ='wednesday'      then  
                                                         wednesday
                  when DATENAME(dw,@dateT)  ='Thursday'         then  
                                                       thursday
                 when DATENAME(dw,@dateT)  ='Friday'               then  
                                                   friday
                 when DATENAME(dw,@dateT)  ='Saturday'           then  
                                                 saturday       


end   feasible
from [CRA_feasibility_test]
```

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: **atmid,@dateT,weekday,'Y' or 'N', nextweekday when it will be 'Y' from the @dateT

Comment: I mean could you post your expect result format like your sample data

Comment: atmid, '2018-06-15' , Friday , N ,  Saturday (Bcoz in tabel it is Y for saturday which happens the day whenthe value will be Y after Friday)  ,Saturday'sDate

Comment: So Do you want to get the next `Y` datetime by parameter `@dateT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try to create a calendar table for next 7 day by `cte recursive`, then use `CROSS APPLY` with `values` make unpivot to get `Y` date which is the closest day.

```
declare @dateT datetime
set @dateT ='2018-06-15'

;with calendar as (
  select @dateT startDt,dateadd(day,7,@dateT) endDt, 1 rn
  union all
  select dateadd(day,1,startDt) , endDt,rn +1
  from calendar
  WHERE  dateadd(day,1,startDt)<endDt
), cte as (
select 
        atmid,v.*
from CRA_feasibility_test cross apply (
    values ('monday',monday), ('tuesday',tuesday), ('wednesday',wednesday), ('thursday',thursday), ('friday',friday), ('saturday',saturday)
) v(name,flag)

)


select atmid,
    @dateT today,
    min(case when flag = 'Y' then startDt end) nextYDay,
    datename(dw,min(case when flag = 'Y' then startDt end) ) nextYname
from calendar t1 
join cte t2 on datename(dw,startDt) = t2.name
group by atmid
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b7e7f5b8bd3ea25f90d09ee9d4a8ade)

**Result**

```
atmid       today               nextYDay            nextYname
DA0068C1    15/06/2018 00:00:00 16/06/2018 00:00:00 Saturday
```

Comment: This is Perfect ! Working :)

Comment: @RubinaK No problem glad to help you can upvote if that help you:)

Comment: Just one more thing, if the flag for dateT turns out to be N then no action needs to be performed, the above logic should happen if flag turns out to be Y for dateT